# K2: How may I open a file in a new window unless I already have such a window open?

Tags: k2

I have a K2 Smartform that displays a list of file names. When the user clicks a file name, the program opens that file (all of them are PDFs) in a new tab in the browser (IE). This is good so far. If you click on a second file from the list, it opens in a third tab. That is not what the user wants.

They want the second file selection to open in the same window as the first file.

This is the process I can see:

1. Click on the file in the list.
2. Open in a tab.
3. Click on a second file in the list.
4. If there is already a tab open with a file from the list, open this file there. Otherwise, open a new tab for the file.

I suppose automatically closing the first tab when they click on the second file would accomplish the same thing.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

When you deal with opening links, first of all, what you can do is limited. Indeed, browsers (IE, Chrome, etc...) can be configured by the users to open links in new tabs, windows, etc... and you as form developer cannot change that.

I have made a jsfiddle to reproduce your situation and propose a solution you can test. I don´t guaranty it will work as I use a Mac but I also describe a better solution below.

You can find it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/chevdor/45k40npv/

I guess the first example (#1) is what happens for you at the moment.
Using the 'target' attribute, I tried to implement a solution that may work for you. Click on #2 and #3 and check whether this work.
I cannot test that since I use a Mac.

You can read more about the target attribute here:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp
```

Another solution that would give you more control is to use an iFrame control. I think it comes in standard with SmartForms now. If not, you can for sure get it from the community site. I recommend you create a new View with this iFrame and define one parameter (string) called "url".

Let´s speak in K2 rules languages :)
"When the parameter changed", "and the parameters is defined", if you 'Transfer data' passing your URL to the iFrame control, it will display your doc. If the user clicks another document, it will update the SAME iFrame. With this solution, no tab will ever be involved.

Please note that it will work great for any document supported by your browser. Some types may require a plugin. Other documents (ie zip, etc..) will NOT appear but be downloaded instead.

I hope this helps.
Best regards,
-chevdor

Comment: Hi Frank, did this help you?

Comment: I didn't see this until today. Even though I've been on SE several times since you posted the answer, it did not send the notification. Your answer gave me ideas, but the users don't want an iFrame here. For some reason, maybe the way the list is setup, I have yet to find a way to set the target for the link to a specific window. Setting target="InvoiceTab" would be perfect, but my choices for target on the link are limited to current, new, parent, and modal dialog. I've upvoted but can't accept yet.